# MFMailComposeViewController change to recipients

Tags: xcode, email, nsstring, mfmailcomposer

Hi I would like to enable the user to send e-mail to different e-mail address it depends on the bout ton selected in the table view - All from same view.
My problem is changing the e-mail address of the recipient each time i tried a few things like putting the e-mail address in a String which updates depending on the bout ton pressed but i was not able to get the e-mail address to the to: Tab in the composer.
I am able to fix a spesific e-mail address but i want the to: tab to change each time it is a different recipient.
Any help would be appreciated - 
My current code which returns blank e-mail address is below.
(Mail is my String receiving the correct e-mail address each time).

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposerVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailComposerVC setSubject:@"Iphone App"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:mail]; 

    [mailComposerVC setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSString *BodyText = @"My Name Is:    \n My Phone Number Is:     \n Please Help With:    \n";
    [mailComposerVC setMessageBody:BodyText isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposerVC animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your toRecipients?

Why don't you just do:

```
NSString *email1 = @"Person1@gmail.com"

NSString *email2 = @"Person2@gmail.com"

//if logic
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:email1];
//if logic
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:email2];
```